# How to use the profile of PROXIMITY PROFILE,IMMEDIATE ALERT SERVICE and Find Me Profile in android 4.3 BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I am developing an android application where I have to connect to Bluetooth device on Android 4.3.

The goal of this APP is BLE Anti-loss, it can make the buzzer beep on the remote device and I want to implement the **PROXIMITY PROFILE** and **Find Me PROFILE**.

I reference the sample of [BluetoothLeGatt](http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/) in Android API18 and I can scan, connect and discover the services.

I found the UUID of Immediate Alert is 0x1802, but I did not found the UUID for Find Me PROFILE and PROXIMITY PROFILE at Bluetooth Developer portal.

And if I got the UUID, how to use this UUID to make the buzzer beep on the remote device.

Does anyone have an android application sample for **Immediate Alert**, **PROXIMITY PROFILE** and **Find Me PROFILE**?

Or can show me how to use UUID to achieve the required functionality?

Comment: Any success testing the PROXIMITY profile? Is it supported by Android? Can we implement proximity profile on our own and limit the proximity signals?

Comment: I use BluetoothGatt.readRemoteRssi(); to get the RSSi. When it out of rang, it will notify!

Comment: Thanks :) If I'm not wrong, the RSSI value depends on the number of factors. i.e the objects between beacon and the central device, the reflective surfaces, weather etc. How are you deciding the value?

Comment: I choose the RSSI in dynamic. I know the RSSI it is unstable. But PROXIMITY PROFILE use the TX power, I think it is similar RSSI.

Answer (score 3):

They are two different things: `RSSI` and `TX_POWER`.

`TX_POWER` is a power that was used to transmit the signal.
`RSSI` is a power of the signal measured by the receiver.

It is always true: `TX_POWER >= RSSI`.
(Since you can't measure power greater than it was actually transmitted)

To monitor proximity between two devices (Transmitter & Receiver, or, Peripheral & Central) you should use the following equation:

`Proximity Level = TX_POWER - RSSI`

The intuition behind this is as follows, the transmitter is always transmit with the same power (TX_POWER), but receiver measure RSSI differently, according to the distance (proximity), when it get closer the RSSI value is getting bigger, and when it moves away the RSSI value is getting smaller.

Good luck!

Comment: "It is always true: TX_POWER >= RSSI. " that is not truth. TX_POWER is rssi on 1m distance. You can calculate distance using txPower and rssi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784516/estimating-beacon-proximity-distance-based-on-rssi-bluetooth-le/27550658#27550658