# Use Find Me Profile in Android 4.3

Tags: android, bluetooth, profile

I a trying to understand and modify the BLE sample von Android.com, now I can discover my sample BLE Device (HTC Fetch) and now I want to understand all that GATT and BLE stuff.

What are Characteristics and what are Profile and what are Serivces and what do they mean in the Bluetooth Low Energy World? I used HTC Dev and found a Service and a Characteristics UUID.

https://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk/bluetooth-smart/htc-fetch/

But I guess what I need is the Find Me Profile, cause for the first steps I only want to get the Find Me react to a Button click.

https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/profiles/Pages/ProfileViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.profile.find_me.xml

How to implement this in my App?

When I understand everything I try Power and Proximity (reading RSSI and compare with defined range).

Can some one help me understanding Bluetooth LE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a related post

[How to use the profile of PROXIMITY PROFILE,IMMEDIATE ALERT SERVICE and Find Me Profile in android 4.3 BLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440707/how-to-use-the-profile-of-proximity-profile-immediate-alert-service-and-find-me)

Basically you can approximate a proximity level using tx+power - rssi  or distance roughly with 
d = (rssi-A)/-20 (where A = rssi at one meter) or simply use rssi mapping out ranges to display You could also initially base it on just the connection range and skip rssi.

As for the FindMe, simply write the low or high alert values to make it sound when you press a button in your app.  For pressing a button on the device use the UUIDs shown in the documentation.

sample code for that device is forthcoming